# Debug problems with specific (worked for 7 years) launch.json configurations

Tags: ruby, debugging

I recently uninstalled ruby 3.1.2 and VSCode due to a problem debugging programs.  I re-installed ruby 3.1.4 and  VSCode.

My Configuration is:  Windows 11, rubyinstaller-devkit-3.1.4-1-x64 , VSCodeSetup-x64-1.82.2

Ruby debug Gems: debug (1.8.0, 1.6.3),  ruby-debug-ide (0.7.3)
VSCode Extensions: Ruby  v0.28.1,  VS Code plugin for connecting with the Ruby LSP Ruby Solargraph v0.24.0'  Ruby's rdbg debugger support for VSCode,  VSCode Ruby v0.28.0

My Launch.json file: That i have used since 2016 is

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [   
    {            "name": "MAIN",
        "type": "Ruby",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.rb"
    },
```

If I select this config for debug I get
"Debugger error: Client: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1234"
There is NO Debug toolbar displayed an program is not executed and tcpview shows "ruby.exe,33588,TCP,Listen,127.0.0.1,1234,0.0.0.0,0,9/21/2023 4:17:33 PM,ruby.exe,,,,"
the connection is not released unless killed in tcpview

I created the new Launch.json entry below which appears to work as desired

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [   
    {   "type": "rdbg",
    "name": "MAIN NEW ",
   "request": "launch",|        
   "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
   "script": "${workspaceRoot}/main.rb"
     },
```

If i select this entry it debugs correctly.

BUT if after running this I go back and select the first config it runs slightly differently
Same symptoms as before except now get a debug toolbar (prog does not execute)
and when I close it (sqr box) the connection is released in tcpview  and I can run multiple
times and connection is released each time (as long as have debug bar). Afterwords can still
debug prog under config 2.

Have several questions

1. Not to concerned about fixing entry 1 but wonder why stopped working after 7 years.  Should this work and if so where would
   I start in resolving this.
2. Is entry 2 the correct way to display  multiple standalone .rb files by filename in the debug drop-down list or is there a better way.
   If I have a group of example files (like glimmer) I like to be able to select file via debug dropdown list
3. 3. is there a tutorial on creating ruby launch.json file for vscode tried to follow in vscode itself and it skipped some of the
      variables i was interested .  Can find nothing useful all in one place the best i have seen is but does not explain all variables

"https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KoichiSasada.vscode-rdbg"

4. I tried to follow "Put gem "debug", require: false in your Gemfile and run bundle install." and wound up getting no place. I have no gemfiles in any of my projects, do they have to be created manually for each.  have followed but it does not make this clear.

[https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/gemfile.5.html"](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/gemfile.5.html%22)

=========================update=========================

Believe have a handle on question 4.  I created a Gemfile at "Open Folder" location and entered the following lines.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby "3.1.4" , :patchlevel => "223"
gem "debug", require: false
gem "nokogiri"
```

then in VSCode terminal ran "bundle install" .  This created a Gemfile.lock in same directory.  So looks like it is working as I would expect.

Adding gem "debug", require: false made no difference to my debug problems.

=========================update=========================
Sept 26 As per user3285799 " I fixed it by downgrading VSCode from 1.82 to 1.76."
I had an install file VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.73.1.exe on mys system and dropped back to it.  Problems disappeared both configurations ran fine (made no extension changes).  Removed and reinstalled VSCodeSetup-x64-1.80.2 (2023_08_03 06_09_33 UTC).exe (which was what I thought I had previous) and both config entries still worked.Then realized was not most recent version i had installed.  Installed VSCodeSetup-x64-1.82.2.exe now problem was back with config 1.  So started occurring in version 1.81 or 1.82 Note 1.80 that worked used all same extensions as 1.82 that did not work.

So a change was made to vscode that caused problem.  I will forget about config 1 and go forward with config 2.

As far as launch.json entry documentation found

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Also found if go to launch.json and into the "type" entry and hit control space it will list many (but not all) of the paymasters for that "type"

So will consider all issues closed at this moment but do have one new issue

If i bring up a user cmd box and run irb show_cmds I get

```
    C:\Users\DNLocal>irb
irb(main):001> show_cmds
Cannot access file C:\Users\DNLocal\-R
=> nil
irb(main):002>
```

But many other commands appear to work
If i bring up a user administrator box and run irb it works

Can find no reference to" file C:\Users\DNLocal-R"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed it by downgrading VSCode from 1.82 to 1.76.
Also stop auto-updating the VSCode version by
File>User Settings>Settings
Update:Mode should be set "none".